# Adding Contents of multiple files using awk

Tags: awk, gawk

Say I have some files named `file1, file2, file3`, ... that have the following format

file1

```
blah blah blah
[PATTERN0]
a10
a20
a30
[PATTERN1]
a11
a21
a31
[PATTERN3]
a13
a13
a33
```

file 2

```
blah blah blah
[PATTERN0]
b10
b20
b30
[PATTERN1]
b11
b21
b31
[PATTERN3]
b13
b13
b33
```

What I would like to do is end up with a file that contains the sum of each individual entry for all files after the specific pattern (i.e. PATTERN0). For instance the file should have

```
a10+b10
a20+b20
a30+b30
```

So far I can only rrad and print the values using

```
awk '/PATTERN0/ {for(i=1; i<=3; i++) {getline;print $1}}' file*
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: may be concatenate the input files column wise using paste and then use awk?

Comment: @Sundeep : Thank you for your comment! I don't know what do you mean :( I am a bit familiar with `paste` in `awk` but I can't make the connection on how to use `paste` first, unless you are referring to something else.

Comment: I meant like `paste file* > combined.txt` so that each line of the files get combined in single line separated by a delimiter (tab by default)... then you read that file and use awk.. but seems you have a simple awk alone solution :)

Comment: @Sundeep : I really like the idea with `paste`! I will try to find a way! Is it possible to post an answer with that?

Comment: Give us usable sample input files: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`, assuming you always have at least two files, that all files have the same number of lines between `[PATTERN0]` and `[PATTERN1]`, and that said lines are actually numbers:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        # discard the garbage before [PATTERN0]
        for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) {
            do      
                getline str <ARGV[i]
            while (str !~ /\[PATTERN0\]/)
        }

        # read sum from first file, then add numbers in turn from the other files
        while ((getline sum <ARGV[1]) && sum !~ /\[PATTERN1\]/) {
            for (i = 2; i < ARGC; i++) {
                getline nr <ARGV[i]
                sum += nr
            }
            print sum
        }
    }' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I created a script called `script.awk` and I am running it using `awk -f script.awk` but I get the following error `awk -f script.awk 
awk: script.awk:1: awk '
awk: script.awk:1:     ^ invalid char ''' in expression
awk: script.awk:1: awk '
awk: script.awk:1:     ^ syntax error`

Comment: @Thanos My script doesn't contain character `'`. _shrug_

Comment: @SatKatsura : I am not I understand what you mean...

Comment: @Thanos You made an error when pasting my script.

Comment: What I pasted is the following `awk '
    BEGIN {
        # discard the garbage before [PATTERN0]
        for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) {
            do      
                getline str <ARGV[i]
            while (str !~ /\[PATTERN0\]/)
        }

        # read sum from first file, then add numbers in turn from the other files
        while ((getline sum <ARGV[1]) && sum !~ /\[PATTERN1\]/) {
            for (i = 2; i < ARGC; i++) {
                getline nr <ARGV[i]
                sum += nr
            }
            print sum
        }
    }' test1.txt test2.txt`

Comment: What you need to put in `script.awk` is the string between `awk '` and `' file1 ...`.  The `'` are not part of the script.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of paste + awk gives nice results:

```
$ paste -d"+" file1 file2 |awk -F"[+]" '/PATTERN/{print $1;next}1'
```

I call awk to avoid having `[PATTERN0]+[PATTERN0]` - you can either remove it or if you don't want `[PATTERN]` to be printed at all change last awk to
`...|awk -F"[+]" '/PATTERN/{next}1`

Testing:

```
$ paste -d"+" <(echo "$a") <(echo "$b") |awk -F"[+]" '/PATTERN/{next}1'
a10+b10
a20+b20
a30+b30
a11+b11
a21+b21
a31+b31
a13+b13
a13+b13
a33+b33
```

Also here is an easy awk solution:

```
$ awk -v RS="[PATTERN[0-9]+]" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) (NR==FNR)?a[RT][i]=$i:a[RT][i]=a[RT][i] "+" $i} \
END{for (k in a) for (l in a[k]) print a[k][l]}' <(echo "$a") <(echo "$b")
```

PS: Above awk is in one-line by removing the `\`. It is split in two lines just for readability here.

Pitfall for this awk is that at END section, printing is correct but in random PATTERN order (i.e `[PATTERN3]` data might be printed first instead of `[PATTERN0]`) due to the way that awk prints arrays with this for method.

Comment: @Thanos Did this worked ok?